# How do I map translated text?

Tags: api, google-translate, yandex-api

This is the link https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=hi&dt=t&q=%20Hello%20World%20how%20are%20you

that returns me the translated text. 
I want to be able to map this way

```
Hello = हैलो
World = वर्ल्ड
how are = कैसे हैं
you = आप
```

Here's is an example of how an Yandex translate returns

https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20170409T062604Z.5b5cee8763ecf005.c64d97c1947190fd6999bca5a73f9ee0df460cb0&lang=en-hi&text=size&text=documentation&text=reader

output :

```
{"code":200,"lang":"en-hi","text":["आकार","प्रलेखन","पाठक"]}
```

So in the yandex I can get the array with mapped size,documentation,reader.

For the above google api I'm unable to get it by adding '&q=' like here in yandex it works by adding '&text='

Comment: Here's my working repo: https://github.com/boro741/free-google-api-translate-test/blob/master/index.html